# custom documentation for C# code

Tags: .net, documentation, documentation-generation

Is there a customizable documentation generator for C#? As opposed to native xml documentation which provides documentations for classes, methods, properties, the documentation I am referring to here is more lower-level, ie it documents the flow of a method.

for example in the given code

```
void SomeMethod(){

///doc:Do X
SomeCodeToDoX

///doc:Do Y
SomeCodeToDoY

///not tagged
SomeCode

}
```

The documentation will capture doc:Do X and doc:Do Y, and will document Do X and Do Y as the flow inside the method SomeMethod

**I hope I made the question clear enough.. if I didn't please comment to ask clarification*

Comment: Interesting idea, though I'd say if your methods are so big and complex that they require documentation *inside* the method, then you probably need to refactor, rather than trying to do this...

Comment: I wouldn't like to expose this kind of comment. It might ward programmers off commenting code "inside the box"

Comment: @graphain: My idea is to have some tag which indicates that this comment is part of the documentation, without the tag the comments would not be documented

Comment: @dean harding: it's not that the methods are big and complex. The requirements demands that the flow of the method be inline-documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this answers your question, but you can use SandCastle: http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/

It creates MSDN documentation by reflecting assemblies. You can (but not required) add your own documentation tags too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use whatever XML elements you like within doc comments, as far as I'm aware - but they have to be attached to a member; you can't just add doc comments to bits of code within a method, I'm afraid.

Or at least, you can, but it won't get picked up as part of the generated XML file and you'll get a warning like this:

> Test.cs(11,9): warning CS1587: XML comment is not placed on a valid language element

It's *possible* that if you disable that warning and use Doxygen to process the source code instead of the built in generator, you *might* be able to get something going... but you should be aware that it will be *very* specific to your environment. I suspect that the benefits wouldn't be worth the pain, myself. I'd also give a warning about the readability of code which has a large amount of comments in - it can get very distracting when you really just want to see the code itself.

(For some reason SO is barfing when I try to post a link to Doxygen... will file a bug on Meta.)